# How to delete current file on exit (in php?)

Tags: php

I know there is a temp file function, but I would like to use create and delete file function on entering and exit from the user (deletes itself on exit). I tried to use both but none worked,

first:

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname(__FILE__);

printf("%s\n", $link);

array_map('unlink', glob("$link/*.php")); 

 ?>
```

2nd:

```
 <?php

$filee = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";   


    printf("%s\n", $link);
    unlink(realpath($filee));

     ?>
```

Comment: Well, the 2nd is a hyperlink, not a local file...

Comment: `array_map('unlink', glob(__DIR__ . '/*.php'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delete (or `unlink`) http URLs. Instead you need to delete FILES.

```
$link = "/tmp/foo.tmp";
unlink($link);
```

Or, to delete all the php files in the directory of your current **FILE** (credit to @Deadooshka above as well as [the top comment on the `php unlink` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) ):

```
array_map('unlink', glob(__DIR__ . '/*.php'));
```

You will notice that we are not prepending the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` onto the beginning of the path.

Comment: `... unlink() can also be used with some URL wrappers ...`

Comment: I never noticed that before, @Deadooshka. However, as per http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php I note that http:// and https:// does NOT support unlink.

Answer (score 1):

For first one:

```
<?php
if(file_exists($filePath)){
    unlink($filePath);
}
?>
```

For second one, you cant unlink any file which is not in your domain.

More over you cant unlink a http request. You have to use relative path, If you will get unlink request in uniform manner, you have to explode and get the file name, frame relative path then unlink it

Comment: Are you saying if it's in your domain you can unlink an http URL? That doesn't seem to fit with the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) - have you verified that?

Comment: @PeterBowers no, we cant unlink if it is http, What I mean, if it is in our doman then we can explode and take the file name alone then we can unlink. But we cant unlinkit directly. I will update the answer accordingly. Thanks :-)